# How to handle Hot Reloading in a React app, inside Docker, inside WSL?

Tags: reactjs, docker, express, windows-subsystem-for-linux

First of all, this is the repo that I've been talking about: [**`Github`**](https://github.com/FMGordillo/mern-and-docker)

In my Macbook with Docker, this works just fine. But I've been trying to use WLS (Ubuntu inside Windows). I've followed up [this tutorial](https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/setting-up-docker-for-windows-and-wsl-to-work-flawlessly#ensure-volume-mounts-work) on how to handle Docker in WLS (and also how to handle Volumes)

It works, I change the code in my host (Windows) and actually it changes inside the container (Docker inside Linux), **but for some reason, the apps don't refresh**.

I'm using two apps, one is a React app (with `react-scripts`) and other with Express (using `nodemon`). Both don't reload on changes.

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The part about nodemon is answered in this thread: [Nodemon Doesn't Restart in Windows Docker Environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39239686/nodemon-doesnt-restart-in-windows-docker-environment). The short answer is to start nodemon with the -L flag to enable legacy file polling.

Editing this as I found a solution to the react client issue as well. The trick is the use the environment flag - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true for your react container. I have it set in my docker-compose like this:

```
environment:
  - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read: [how to write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) before continuing your life in stackoverflow.

Comment: Thank you! I've read the post, is there anything in particular that was wrong with my reply above?

Comment: Its working for me on windows. Great thanks!! Need to check on linux as well.

Comment: it is not working with my case