# Nodemon not restarting on file change

Tags: node.js, docker, nodemon

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run prod",
    "build": "npm-run-all clean transpile",
    "server": "node ./dist/bin/www",
    "dev": "npm run lint && NODE_ENV=development nodemon --inspect=notifications:9236 --exec babel-node bin/www",
    "prod": "NODE_ENV=production npm-run-all build server",
    "transpile": "babel ./ --out-dir dist",
    "lint": "eslint '*.js' ",
    "lint:watch": "watch 'npm run lint' ",
    "precommit": "npm run lint",
    "prepush": "npm run lint",
    "clean": "rimraf dist",
    "test": "jest"
  }
```

I have multiple microservices on docker, each one contains similar scripts in their package.json.
Whenever I make a change and save the file, nodemon does not detect the change & restart the server.

Nodemon does start when a microservice is booted up, outputting the following:

```
[nodemon] 2.0.15
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): **/* public/**/*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `babel-node --inspect=notifications:9236 bin/www`
```

I have to mention, this is a project built on Mac OS and I am currently running it on Windows, if it is any relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's relevant on windows, because the file system difference in containers that run unix [Duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39239686/nodemon-doesnt-restart-in-windows-docker-environment)

if you setup `nodemon.json` to poll changes it should update, but it is very expensive memory wise

```
{
 "verbose": true,
 "watch": ["src/**/*.ts"],
 "exec": "ts-node ./src/index.ts",
 "pollingInterval": 100,
 "legacyWatch": true
}
```

Comment: Adding legacyWatch did the trick. I've seen this before in other questions but what I didn't realize is that we use the config for nodemon in our package.json instead of a different json.

The fact that you wrote out a more complete config helped me find it out in our project. Thanks. :)

Comment: `"legacyWatch": true` fixed it for me on Windows 11

Answer (score 0):

In whatever start script you are trying to run, you need to include `nodemon`

ex:

```
"start": "nodemon run prod"
```

Comment: I have tweaked it to the following:

  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon run prod",
    "build": "npm-run-all clean transpile",
    etc...
  }

Still does not work.

Comment: but did you replace `npm` with `nodemon` for the `build`, as well as all the other ones?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it’s already the case, but do you have your code folder as a volume ? Because if you don’t use a volume to share your local changes with the dockerized files, it won’t update because the files will stay the same

Answer (score 0):

I'm watching files via nodemon `--watch '**/*'` this will finds any changes in the nested files